# c++ progam to take card number

Tags: c++, random

I'm working on the following C++ application:

**Description:**

The user enters a number `n` and the program takes a random collection of cards that are declared at the top of main in the global arrays. It will output a random number of cards each time.

**Issue:**
The number, e.g. '3 Hearts', appears more than one time. I made a function to correct that, however it didn't solve the issue.

Reference code provided below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string type[4] = {"Hearts" , "Diamonds" , "Spades" , "Clubs"};
string num[13] = {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","J","Q","K"};

int random(int x)
{
    return rand() %x;
}

bool isDrawn(int);
void DrawCard();
int card_remaining = 52;
bool card_is_drawn[52] = {false};

int main()
{

    while(1)
    {
       cout<<"\n Enter A Card Number  :   ";
       int n;
       cin>>n; 

       if(card_remaining <= 0)
       {
            card_remaining = 52;
            cout<<" No More Cards  ,  Refreshing ...\n";
            cout<<"  Refresh Done ! Try Again if you Want \n";
            for(int i=0;i<52;i++)
                card_is_drawn[i] = false;
        }
        else
        {
            for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
            {
                DrawCard();
            }
        }
            
    }

    cout<<endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
void DrawCard()
{
    bool check_1 = false;
    int card;
    while(!check_1)
    {
        card = random(card_remaining);
        if(!isDrawn(card))
        check_1 = true;
    }

    if(check_1)
        cout << num[card%13]<<"   OF   " << type[card/13] << endl ;

    card_remaining--;
}

bool isDrawn(int x)
{
    if (card_is_drawn[x] == false)
    {
        card_is_drawn[x] = true;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Is there something preventing you from debugging this in the usual way, e.g. add debug `cout`s and/or step through the code with a debugger ?

Comment: no , even with debugging no errors

Comment: So you say _'it doesn't work'_ and _'no , even with debugging no errors'_, this sounds pretty weird! Perhaps you're confusing logical errors with compilation errors or exceptions.

Comment: I try it with " visual studio 2012 , netbeans , and visual c++ " but not error's , it work , but the problem is with the result of program , it show the number more than one time

Comment: Then go step through with the debugger every single line, to see where the unwanted extra output is done.

Comment: side note: rand() of stdlib.h is to be avoided in C++, refer to: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random

Answer (score 0, accepted):

should be:

```
void DrawCard(){
    if (card_remaining <= 0)    // no cards left? can't draw
        return;

    bool check_1 = false;
    int card;
    while(!check_1){
        card = random(52);  // here 52
        if (isDrawn(card))  // here, if the card HAS been drawn
            check_1 = true;
    }
    if(check_1)
        cout << num[card%13]<<"   OF   " << type[card/13] << endl ;

    card_remaining--;
}
```

Comment: From the design point of view, it is a good practice, but it is not the source of this particular problem, since proper code has been put into main() to ensure that the number of cards will always be greater than 0.

Answer (score 1):

Check the function

```
bool isDrawn(int x){
    if(card_is_drawn[x] == false){
        card_is_drawn[x] = true;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

You might want to exchange the both return values. That means:

```
if(card_is_drawn[x] == false) {
    ...
    return false;    //since the card was NOT drawn;
```

And at the end of the function:

```
return true;    //since the if-clause evaluated as false what means that the card was drawn;
```

By the way:

You get your random card by rand()%cards_remaining. That means if you draw ANY card and therefore reduce cards_remaining by one you won't be able to draw the King of Clubs anymore. And going on like this you will loose cards from the 'end' of your deck.